# The difference between weak topologies generated by all bounded continuous functions and all continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, weak-topology

Let $\{f_i\}$ be the set of all bounded continuous real functions with respect to the usual topology on $R$, and $\{g_i\}$ be the set of all continuous real functions with respect to the usual topology on $R$. Moreover, let $T_1$ be the weak topology on $R$ generated by $\{f_i\}$ and $T_2$ be the weak topology on $R$ generated by $\{g_i\}$. What are the differences between $T_1$ and $T_2$? Are they the same?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both $T_1$ and $T_2$ coincide with the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, if $(a,b)$ is a bounded open interval then considering the bounded continuous function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
& 0 & x <a \\
&x-a& x \in [a,b] \\
& b-a & x >b
 \end{cases}$$
we conclude that $(a,b)=f^{-1}((0,b-a)) \in T_1$. Since each open set is union of such intervals, $T_1$ (and so $T_2$, which is bigger) is the whole euclidean topology.